# Dynamic textbox validation

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my table structure 2 column rate chart and qty :

```
rate   chart   qty
1      -5       1
6     -10       2
11    -20       3
```

I have 3 fields on windows form

- 1 combobox
- 1 textbox
- 1 button

I fetch the ratechart column value through combobox, I have that code but my requirement is if user select 1-5 from combobox, then textbox he cannot enter more than 6 in textbox.

Same if user select 6-10 from combobox , then he cannot enter more than 12 in textbox

while he click on save button he get an error that qty is more..

thx in advance. please help me for this code

Comment: Your table structure shows that it has three columns rate, chart and qty.

Comment: no its 2 column only rate chart :1-5 and qty-:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `cmbRateChart.SelectedValue` contains qty value with respect to RangeChart.

```
private void textBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    bool cancel = false;
    int number = -1;

    if (int.TryParse(this.textBox.Text, out number))
    {
        var validRange = Convert.ToInt32(cmbRateChart.SelectedValue) * 6;
        if (number <= validRange)
            cancel = false; //passed validation.
        else
            cancel = true; //failed validation, number is not in valid range

    }
    else
        cancel = true;//failed validation: text box is not a number
    e.Cancel = cancel;
}
```

Usage: Call this function to check the validation.

```
this.ValidateChildren(ValidationConstraints.Enabled);
```

Reference: [Validation in Windows Forms](http://blog.scosby.com/post/2010/02/11/Validation-in-Windows-Forms.aspx)

Comment: where i have to write this code and you *6 in code , what if user select 6-10...in combobox???

Comment: You can hook Validating event of TextBox for this piece of code. Range 6-10 have a qty 2, which is multiplied with 6, resulting 2 * 6 = 12

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get value from textBox
        int number = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);

        // Get value from combobox
        int selcetedComboValue = Int32.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

        // Validate Values
        if (selcetedComboValue <= 5)
        {
            if (number <= 6)
            {
                // Valid Number 
            }
            else
            {
                // Invalid Number
            }
        }
        else if (selcetedComboValue <= 10)
        {
            if (number <= 12)
            {
                // Valid Number
            }
            else
            {
                // Invalid Number
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: error: input string was not in correct format    int selcetedComboValue = Int32.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

Comment: Its working perfect. I think your combobox values are not numeric.